# Share multiple videos on one page onto facebook page wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook C# SDK to post on fan page wall. (I created FBApp ext...) and using FB connect (Javascript) to user login, with this scope - "publish_actions,manage_pages,publish_stream". after user login i got an access_token to post on the page.

I have a page, and on the page settings "Everyone can add photos and videos to Testpage's timeline" is checked.

I can post message and picture, but when i tried to post a video (Youtube URL), it's appears on section "Recent Posts by Others on Testpage". When the Everyone can add photos and videos to Testpage's timeline" is not checked, I don't see any post.

1. To post a video on page, I must enabled "Everyone can add photos and videos to Testpage's timeline"?
2. When i success to post a video, Why the video appears on "Recent Posts by Others on Testpage"?

My Facebook user is admin on the page and I'm login with this user.

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to get the access token from the user accounts, and not from the FB.Login.

```
string getPagesTokensUrl = string.Format(@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={0}",accessToken);

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var pagesTokens = wc.DownloadString(getPagesTokensUrl);

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(pagesTokens);

            for (int i = 0; i < o["data"].Count(); i++)
            {
                if (o["data"][i]["id"].ToString() == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YOUR PAGE ID"])
                {
                    return o["data"][i]["access_token"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```